# Actual project about using tensorflow LSTM to predict next value with time series data

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm, forecasting, predict

Recently I worked on a problem to predict next day's web views. I choose RNN-LSTM model but the result is not well.

My original data is about 200 days and each day has 1440 point(each day has 1440 minutes and every minute has a value) => **[200 * 1440, 1]**.

After feature engineering, I expand 1-feature which is only web view value to **8-features**(which are index of that day(range from 0 to 1439), web view value, is_weekday(0, 1), which hours of that day(range from 0 to 23), which week day(range from 0 to 6) and so on). **So after this step, the data is like [200 * 1440, 8]**

Then normalized every feature to make it belong to [-1,1].

Then using lstm model. The model arch is like FNN-3*LSTM-2*FNN. The rnn_hidden_unit is 128. I tried to use 30 time_steps to predict next value. For example, t0, t1, ..., t29 -> t30 and t1, t2, ..., t30 -> t31.

1. The first FNN layer is to transform 8-features to 128 so as to make it suit to lstm layer. [batch_size, time_step, n_features] -> [batch_size, time_step, rnn_hidden_unit]
2. The LSTM layer has 3 layers(MultiRNNCell, lstm_depth=3)
3. The last 2*FNN layer is to transform 128 to 64 to 1.

   `last_cell_output = output_rnn[:, -1, :]
   output_layer1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(last_cell_output, num_outputs=64, activation_fn=None)
   pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(output_layer1, num_outputs=1, activation_fn=None)`
4. The loss function: only use the last lstm cell to compute loss.

   `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.reshape(pred, [-1]) - tf.reshape(Y, [-1]))) + regularization_cost`

---

The result is like the followint pic, the blue is real value and the gray area is composed of two value: predict_value*0.8 and predict_value*1.2.

### [image]

But when I choose traditional statistical methods like weighted average using previous 5 weekday if next predicting day is a weekday or previous 2 weekend days if next predicting day is a weekend. The result is well.
[image]

**So are there any methods or tricks to improve the lstm model result? Or my solution itself has some faults.** Thanks very much!

Some important hyper parameters of lstm model:

```
time_step=30 (I also tried 60, 120. And 30 and 60 are well)
rnn_hidden_unit=128
n_features=8
lstm_depth=3
ouput_keep_prob=0.7
l2_regularization_rate=0.001
batch_size=64
```